# Need suggestion on appExchange product available

Tags: metadata, appexchange

Is there any appExchange product available in the market which can give me quick overview of the org and the following components:

1. User Info
2. Number of triggers
3. Number of objects and records in each (maybe some time details, last updated, modified,  show if the data is getting old)
4. Security Information
5. Layouts
6. Profiles